# How to map different namespace in xml schema to different classes

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, apache-axis, spring-ws

I have a requirement where I need to map the different namespace in xml schema to different packages. And the package name should be different from namespace. So if there are 2 namespace defined in my xml schema, `http://sampl.com/firtNamespace` and `http://sampl.com/secondnamesapce`, I want them to map to package , say, `com.myexample.fn1` and `com.myexample.simpleapp`.

I have read that , this can be achieved though jaxb binding file, but I could not get any concrete example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your xml namespaces per package by using the `@XmlSchema` annotation in the `pakcage-info.java` file.

Comment: Ok..But how can I do if I don't have generated classes. I just a xml schema file and I use tools like xjc to generate the classes. So , I want to define namespace-package mapping at class generation level.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using an external JAXB binding file.  Here is the url to the oracle JAXB documentation: [JaXb docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use Maven 2 JAXB 2.x Plugin you can find [here](http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home). The plugin creates JAXB classes based on the XSD files. If your WSDL is composed by, let say, two different schemas with different namespaces (that's you can extract two XSD files), the classes will be generated them in two different packages according with the namespace. With the plugin you can also force the two schema classes to be generated in the same directory, indicating the target package, but that is not what you so take care and do not use that option.